# Exception "stylesheet is too complex" when loading large XSLT in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, xslt, .net-4.5

I am getting an exception when attempting to load an XSLT stylesheet.  The XSLT stylesheet is very large (almost 8,000 lines). Unfortunately, I do not have any control over this, and I am unable to refactor the stylesheet to make it smaller.

We recently upgraded to .Net Framework 4.5. The following command below worked just fine prior to the upgrade (we were using .Net Framework 4.0).  After the upgrade we receive an `XsltException` that says "The stylesheet is too complex" on the`transform.Load` line.

I was hoping there was some new setting that would say "Make this command work the way it did in 4.0", but I could not find anything anywhere.

Does anybody know of some reason why this might suddenly be a problem in the 4.5 version? How can it be resolved?

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(report), new XsltSettings { EnableScript = true }, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

`report` is a MemoryStream which contains the large XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: [Please don't use tags in your question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/189763)

Comment: @RyanGates Reads much better now.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Please **do** use topic keywords in your question title, if they're important for clarifying the topic (even if they also happen to be tags). The sole answer to the question @Ryan linked to actually recommends using topic keywords (that are also tags) in a title like "Can I use jQuery to ..." The word *stylesheet* is ambiguous enough that qualifying it with *XSLT* in the title is worthwhile.

Comment: Yes @RyanGates, while the original title was lengthy, it clearly stated the issue, while the new title you gave it was far more ambiguous: What kind of stylesheet (CSS?); What platform (FireFox?, Java?). An ambiguous title forces people to needlessly open the question to find out what it's about.

Comment: I am in the wrong here. I personally don't think that the title is ambiguous if you look at the tags. That being said, upon reading the link more closely I can see what you mean about the distinction between organic and forced.

Comment: Gene S., I believe that you must be thankful for getting this error. 8000 lines of code would roughly fit on 134 pages -- who would ever wish to be assigned to maintain this? 10 years ago I found a 29-page C# method in my client's code and was stunned -- now *this* beats all records.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. It doesn't happen with the old `XslTransform` either. It seems to be going into a recursive method `at System.Xml.Xsl.Qil.QilDepthChecker.Check(QilNode input, Int32 depth)` where it dies. I couldn't find out how to get the source for that for any clues either.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The stylesheet is dynamically generated based on user input.  Most of the time the generated stylesheet is small, on very rare occasions it gets very large.  The stylesheet only lives in memory while the process runs, so there is no maintenance.

Comment: 8000 lines doesn't sound very large to me - about the same as the stylesheets we use for generating the W3C specs. docbook is surely quite a bit bigger.

You could always try a different XSLT processor...

Comment: Hello, I am from .NET Framework Compatibility team. We would like to understand this better. Can you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com with small project to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Varun Email has been sent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out this is a feature/defect in the .Net Framework 4.5.  Message from Microsoft...

*We recently released a fix for this in a hotfix rollup. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828843 for .NET Framework 4.0 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828841 for .NET Framework 4.5.*

Then add this to your config file and the problem should go away.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.xml">
      <section name="xslt" type="System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XsltConfigSection, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.xml>
    <xslt limitXPathComplexity="false"/>
  </system.xml>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: @Sprague That is correct.  For some reason Microsoft requires you to contact them to get the Hotfix.  But there is a link on each of the KB pages that provides a way to contact Microsoft.

Comment: I don't like this, I don't like it one bit. By the time I get what I want from them, I will have debugged the hard way (I have actually done just that...)

Comment: Interesting, when I contacted them I got the hotfix the same day.

Comment: I never claimed to have attempted to contact them. Anyway, that's not important. The KB could have been more to the point, at least. A download link would have been excellent.

Comment: Actually this only shifts the Problem from Parsing/Compiling the XSLT to Executing it. It seems that this is a Security Feature against Stack Overflows that MS built in. 
Deactivating it resulted in Stack Overflows with our 3000 Chars XSLT. As you know SOs cannot be caught and will terminate the process, so this is quite risky! We have refactored the XSLT by introducing Variables for frequently used Node-Sets, but ultimately had to start a custom Worker Thread Pool with increased Stack Size to handle the XSLTs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and isolated it to a machine-generated choice-element with more than 1500 xsl:when-elements. Further testing proved .NET 4.7 will give the "too complex" exception at 789 when-elements or more.

Setting limitXPathComplexity to false in app.config crashes the program with an StackOverflowException instead.

The same code on .NET Core 2.0 throws StackOverflowException at appx 2800 elements. I have reported the bug to both teams, but don't expect it to be prioritized anytime soon.

Comment: It seems that this is a Security Feature against Stack Overflows that MS built in. We have refactored the XSLT by introducing Variables for frequently used Node-Sets, but ultimately had to start a custom Worker Thread Pool with increased Stack Size of 2MB to handle the XSLTs esp. on the IIS where Stack Size is only 256/512kB for 32/64Bit Processes. That works so far.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by replacing thousands of xsl:choose and xsl:if statements being used for key/value mapping with an external xml file key/value lookup.

Plagiarised method here - credits below.

In terms of XSLT the best way is to have the lookup data as an XML document that you could then load with the XSLT document function. For instance if you have your lookup XML in the form of e.g.

```
<list>
  <data key="k1" value="value 1"/>
  <data key="k2" value="value 2"/>
  <data key="k3" value="value 3"/>
</list>
```

then with XSLT you can do e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="data" select="document('lookup.xml')/list/data"/>

<xsl:for-each select="foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="$data[@key = current()]/@value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

No need to xsl:choose. Of course the document function does not have to load a static file, it could make a GET request to a HTTP server that serves up the XML.

credits:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b5966a1-aa1e-46db-88f8-3f4a9aeadb5b/best-way-to-handle-a-lookup-in-xslt-data-is-already-in-a-database?forum=xmlandnetfx

http://etutorials.org/XML/xml+hacks/Chapter+3.+Transforming+XML+Documents/Hack+56+Use+Lookup+Tables+with+XSLT+to+Translate+FIPS+Codes/